# Nuget package install command throws error : Install-Package Crystal Decision -Version 13.0.3500

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to install Crystal Decision version 13.0.3500.0 into my local code But I am getting error like

```
  **Install-Package : Package 'CrystalReports.Engine 13.0.3500' is not found in the following 
    primary source(s): 
    'http://abcv.it.vbn.net/repository/nuget-drs-ms,C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
    SDKs\NuGetPackages\'. Please verify all your 
    online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Install-Package CrystalReports.Engine -Version 13.0.3500
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
    NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand**
```

any clue to solve this issue or error? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried command:

Install-Package CrystalReports.Engine -Version 13.0.3500

Comment: if not work do this : 
Package Manager Settings->General->Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

Comment: yes I tried to install it from nuget command line but it throws this error

Comment: @wikiCan cleared cache also but nothing works

Comment: Dear ZMAX, have you tried in new sample project latest version of Crystal Report?

Comment: @Dharmeshsharma no . can you paste any link . so that I can install it into my local project .

Comment: This is nuget link https://www.nuget.org/packages/CrystalReports.Engine/ and If in case its not working you can directly download from Crystal Report site and install with VS so no nuge required in case https://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/

Comment: @Dharmeshsharma thanks :) .. nuget package link solved my issue